# gSoap - parse custom http header from request

Tags: rest, http-headers, gsoap

I'm trying to find some information on how to parse out custom http headers received in a request by a gSoap server application.  I've spent several hours trying to find any documentation on this but so far I haven't been successful.

I see plenty of documentation on how to **set** custom http headers for both the client and server (such as via the http_extra_header property), but not on how to read them from a request that was received.  It seems like gSoap supports parsing out existing standardized headers (eg: X-Forwarded-For) but so far I can't figure out how to access headers that aren't already defined.  I'm usually good at searching for stuff like this, but I keep hitting on documentation for gSoap header **files**, **soap** headers, or **setting** http headers.  Nothing so far on receiving and parsing out custom headers that aren't already well-defined.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a callback function to process HTTP headers, see [callback functions](https://www.genivia.com/doc/guide/html/group__group__callbacks.html) and in particular the [fparsehdr callback](https://www.genivia.com/doc/guide/html/group__group__callbacks.html#ga70b75026b5fb1a9a2d5779f72454f082):

> Callback that consumes an HTTP header that consists of a key-value
>   pair.
>
> This callback is called by soap::fparse, consumes an HTTP header that
>   is split in a key-value pair and updates the soap context state
>   accordingly.

Assign this callback and use the HTTP header key and value pair passed to it. Make sure to call the original `soap->fparsehdr(soap, key, val)` in the new callback, to let the engine process all headers by passing them through to the original callback:

```
soap->user = (void*)soap->fparsehdr; // to call fparsehdr() in our callback
soap->fparsehdr = my_parsehdr;
```

The new callback function:

```
typedef int(*PARSEFUNC)(struct soap*, const char*, const char*);
int my_parsehdr(struct soap *soap, const char *key, const char *val)
{
  ... // check key (non-NULL) and use val (non-NULL)
  return ((PARSEFUNC)(soap->user))(soap, key, val);
}
```

I recommend to pass all headers through to the engine, unless it is a custom header that has no meaning to the engine.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you!